# Antd Menu - why is there space even when I use space-between property?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I've already used `justify-content: space-between`, but there are still spacing in the front and last.
[image]

demo.js

```
import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Menu } from "antd";
import {
  MailOutlined,
  AppstoreOutlined,
  SettingOutlined
} from "@ant-design/icons";

const App = () => (
  <Menu
    mode="horizontal"
    defaultSelectedKeys={["mail"]}
    style={{ border: "1px solid grey", justifyContent: "space-between" }}
  >
    <Menu.Item key="mail" icon={<MailOutlined />}>
      Navigation One
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.SubMenu
      key="SubMenu"
      title="Navigation Two - Submenu"
      icon={<SettingOutlined />}
    >
      <Menu.Item key="two" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
        Navigation Two
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="three" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
        Navigation Three
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.ItemGroup title="Item Group">
        <Menu.Item key="four" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
          Navigation Four
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="five" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
          Navigation Five
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu.ItemGroup>
    </Menu.SubMenu>
    <Menu.Item key="mail" icon={<MailOutlined />}>
      Navigation Six
    </Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);

export default App;
```

CodeSandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-deprecated-syntactic-sugar-antd-4-22-4-forked-m4p6vh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The CSS justify-content property defines how a browser distributes
> available space between and around elements when aligning flex items
> in the main-axis of the current line. The alignment is done after the
> lengths and auto margins are applied, meaning that, if there is at
> least one flexible element, with flex-grow different than 0, it will have no effect as there won't be any available space.

Since you use pseudoelements, it takes it as one of items. By removing :before it should work

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
 .ant-menu::before {
    display: table;
    content: '';
 }
```

Remove content: '', or this ::before pseudoelement at all.